# Re-sizing and moving web site images and text divs to work with dynamic background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to figure this one out for a while now. Any help would be appreciated !

I can't seem to find a way to properly scale my text and an image button s according to the resolution and the browser size. I tried applying various techniques such as CSS, Jquery, and even made the font size scale down as the browser window's being re-sized. How can I make all layers dynamic so when resized the whole thing, all divs stay in sync ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest looking into responsive web design. The whole idea is to create a website that is suitable under a variety of viewing environments.

[This episode of doctype.tv](http://doctype.tv/jquery15) has a good introduction then check out [this article on elated.com](http://www.elated.com/articles/responsive-web-design-demystified/) that will give you a better understanding of it.

Good luck and I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The example (http://livestutterfree.com/page/) you give just set:
listen the "resize" event of "window" and try to calculate a proper value of each thing, and there are not much div, image and text so that it can be reset one by one.

if you want have so much div, image and text, it is not a good way to do like "http://livestutterfree.com/page/" obviously. so if the browser support the "transform" (a css3 property), you can try to set "transform: scale" on the top level div when the window is resized.

Answer (score 0):

firstly, you should put your background images directly on the divs which you want to adjust based on the size, for example right on your content or logo div.  also, the fact that you are using fixed positioning is messing with the ability of the elements to resize. use margins or floats to get things positioned correctly.